# undifined is not object this.props.navigation (onOpened notification)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I try to navigate when I open a notification which is in my app.js but it says:

> undefined is not an object (this.props.navigation )

I'm using react-navigation to navigate between screens.

app.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    OneSignal.init('my-id');

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    OneSignal.configure();  // triggers the ids event
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived(notification) {
      console.log('Notification received: ', notification);
  }

  onOpened(openResult) {
      console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
      console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
      console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
      console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('EventHistoryComponent',openResult);
  }

  onIds(device) {
      console.log('Device info: ', device);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is a classic JS problem, you call something (property or function) on nothing (that's why you're being told it is undefined). In your case, it probably comes from the fact that your function `onOpened` is not bind to `this`. It is also a classic problem with React, stated in their documentation. Please check how to use `bind()`.

Comment: Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to understand how `this` works in JavaScript

Comment: thanks for answering me . i add `this.onOpened=this.onOpened.bind(this)` but still the same error.

Comment: First, did you accurately identify what's `undefined`?
Try something like: 
`console.log(this);console.log(this.props);console.log(this.props.navigation);console.log(this.props.navigation.navigate);`
Make sure to know what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.props.navigation` only exists in screens within your `AppNavigator`.
If you want to navigate outside of components nested within `AppNavigator`, `react-navigation` [has a guide for this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html).